# How to classify images with the same pattern, differing in color?

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, kullback-leibler, computer-vision

In order to increase your knowledge in the field of computer vision, I would like to create an application that will classify photos with the same pattern but with different colors. Is there any chances to classify images with the same pattern, differing in color? For now I use local binary pattern to create histogram and then I compare histogram by entropy. I have problem with pictures with same same pattern(for example, photos of a carpets or wall tiles).
Below is my code in python, and sample pictures. The first picture (type1_1) and the second picture (type1_2) have the same pattern but they differ in color. I can not classify them properly.

```py
     import numpy as np
        from skimage.color import label2rgb
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from skimage.feature import local_binary_pattern
        from skimage import data
        from skimage.color import label2rgb
        #To calculate a normalized histogram
        from scipy.stats import itemfreq
        from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
        #To read class from file
        import cv2
        #To calculate entropy
        from scipy.stats import entropy
        
        #LBP parameters
        radius = 3
        n_points = 8 * radius
        
        METHOD = 'uniform'
        plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 9
        
        path_to_image_type1_1 = 'path/to/typ1_1.png'
        path_to_image_type1_2 = 'path/to/typ1_2.png'
        path_to_image_type2_1 = 'path/to/typ2_1.png'
        path_to_image_type3_1 = 'path/to/typ3_1.png'
        
        def kullback_leibler_divergence(p, q):
            p = np.asarray(p)
            q = np.asarray(q)
            filt = np.logical_and(p != 0, q != 0)
            return np.sum(p[filt] * np.log2(p[filt] / q[filt]))
        
        def entropy_classification(t1, t2):
            return entropy(pk=t1, qk=t2)
        
        def match(refs, img):
            best_score = 10
            best_name = None
            lbp = local_binary_pattern(img, n_points, radius, METHOD)
            n_bins = int(lbp.max() + 1)
            hist, _ = np.histogram(lbp, normed=True, bins=n_bins, range=(0, n_bins))
            for name, ref in refs.items():
                ref_hist, _ = np.histogram(ref, normed=True, bins=n_bins,
                                           range=(0, n_bins))
                #score = kullback_leibler_divergence(hist, ref_hist)
                entropy_score = entropy_classification(hist, ref_hist)
                if entropy_score < best_score:
                    best_score = entropy_score
                    best_name = name
            return best_name
        
        def hist(ax, lbp):
            n_bins = int(lbp.max() + 1)
            return ax.hist(lbp.ravel(), normed=True, bins=n_bins, range=(0, n_bins), facecolor='0.5')
        
        def read_image(path_to_image):
            image = cv2.imread(path_to_image)
            gaussian_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, (5,5), 0)
            gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(gaussian_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            return gray_image
        
        gray_image_type1_1 = read_image(path_to_image_type1_1)
        gray_image_type1_2 = read_image(path_to_image_type1_2)
        gray_image_type2_1 = read_image(path_to_image_type2_1)
        gray_image_type3_1 = read_image(path_to_image_type3_1)
        
        refs = {
            'type1': local_binary_pattern(gray_image_type1_1, n_points, radius, METHOD),
            'type2': local_binary_pattern(gray_image_type2_1, n_points, radius, METHOD),
            'type3': local_binary_pattern(gray_image_type3_1, n_points, radius, METHOD)
        }
        
        print('Original: typ1_2, matched: ',
              match(refs, gray_image_type1_2))
        print('Original: typ2_1, matched: ',
              match(refs, gray_image_type2_1))
        print('Original: typ3_1, matched: ',
              match(refs, gray_image_type3_1))
```

Is there any better solution for this vision task?

Comment: Did you try histogram equalization?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have not tried it yet. I'll check it.

Comment: It helped me reduce the problem with different lighting conditions, but my problem still exists. I don't know why the entropy of histograms of images with the same patterns is larger than images with different patterns. Maybe LBP and entropy are not the best solution for my classification. I am looking for something to get only the edges and then find the characteristic geometrical figure. I tried to use Canny Edge. Can you tell me something else, what should I try?

Comment: Did you try to convert the images to grayscale and then do histogram equalization?

Comment: Yes, first I do grayscale and then histogram equalization. After than I normalize histogram by this:                                                                   `def calculate_histogram(img_eq):
    lbp = local_binary_pattern(img_eq, n_points, radius, METHOD)
    n_bins = int(lbp.max() + 1)
    hist, _ = np.histogram(lbp, normed=True, bins=n_bins, range=(0, n_bins))
    return hist`

Comment: Is there a better way to compare two histograms than entropy? I am looking for a reason why the entropy of two different patterns is smaller than the entropy of the same patterns. For different patterns, the value is 0.00137, for identical ones it is equal to 0.001442. The difference is very small.